# NoMethodError: undefined method `safe_constantize'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a simple model:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

It has a column `INT` named `type`

When I create a record:

```
Post.create(:type => 1)
```

I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `safe_constantize' for 1:Fixnum
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Like it is: There are no method called `safe_constantize` on a Fixnum.

`type` is for [Single Table Inheritance](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Single+table+inheritance). You would usually put a string representation of a known model in your application as a `type` value. See [rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html#schema-conventions)

Comment: Basically, don't conflict with Rails' specialized column names. `:category` is what I ended up calling my column.